# Convert a string, char type to System.Windows.Forms.Keys

Tags: c#, types, char, key

I'm trying to get a char converted to System.windows.Form.Keys type or a string to a Keys array. Does anyone know how to do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Keys` codes for the numbers and uppercase letters match the corresponding ASCII codes. Assuming you're dealing with ASCII, you can do:

```
Keys key = (Keys) (byte) char.ToUpper(c);
```

Comment: How do you do this if it's not w/in that range?

Comment: @Geesu, the `Keys` type only contains the uppercase letters and the numbers from a US keyboard. Non-ASCII characters, lowercase letters and symbols will vary for different keyboard layouts. If you want to use non-ASCII letters then you'll need to use something else.